# What is the correct way to structure a try catch statement to only allow integers

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, try-catch, case

The problem I have with this is the program displays like this

1
Please Enter the name 
red
Please Enter the price of this event

red

Please Enter the price of this event

40

Please Enter the date of this event

Please enter the amount of tickets available for this event.

It completely skips the date. How can I edit my code so that I can enter the data correctly.

Any tips and advice would be great. What is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks

My code is

case 1:

```
 char ans;
    do{                 
        Event event = new Event();
        out.println("Please Enter the name ");
        event.setEvent(input.next());
        input.nextLine();

        do {
            try {
                out.println("Please Enter the price of this event\n");
                event.setprice(input.nextDouble());
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                out.println("Please Enter the price of this event\n");
            }
            input.nextLine();
        } while (!input.hasNextDouble());

        out.println("Please Enter the date of this event\n");
        event.setdate(input.next());

        out.println("Please enter the amount of tickets available for this event.\n");
                event.setavailability(input.nextInt());

        out.println("Please enter");
        event.setvenue(input.next());
        Events.add(event);

        out.println("Would you like to add a new event?");
        String answer = input.next();
        ans = answer.charAt(0);

        while (ans== 'y');      
            out.println (Events.get(0));
            break;
        }
```

Comment: While StackOverflow is a place where many of your programming questions are answered its not a place where your homework gets done for you.   My advice if you will is to question your calls to input and whether you want to consume from it or test it.

Comment: You appear to be mixing `input.next()` (and its cousins) with `input.nextLine()`--you shouldn't do that.  When gathering input from the console, you should use `input.nextLine()` and then parse what the user typed.  Things will go smoother if you do that.

Comment: Forget about exceptions for awhile.  As Jared suggests, you need to understand the difference between the various methods on Scanner.  Write some toy programs and play with that for awhile.

Comment: Without the exceptions my code works fine.
For example 

'code' case 1:
    
    char ans;
    
    do{
     
     Event event = new Event();
     
     
     out.println("Please Enter the name ");
     event.setEvent(input.next());
     input.nextLine();
 
     out.println("Please Enter the price of this event\n");
     event.setprice(input.nextDouble());
   
     out.println("Please Enter the date of this event\n");
     event.setdate(input.next());
'code'    
    
Should I be inputting this in a different way?

Answer (score -1):

The following piece of code displays a **JFrame** with a **JLabel** , a **TextField** & a **JButton**. If you enter an integer, it would display a **JOptionPane** saying... Accepted. Else it would display a **JOptionPane** with error message. I think you might expected to handle **NumberFormatException**. You should update your question else it would be voted down. Following code handles  **NumberFormatException**.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ExceptionTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField jtf;

    public ExceptionTest() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        add(jp);
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Enter price");
        jp.add(lbl);
        jtf = new JTextField(9);
        jp.add(jtf);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click to check");
        btn.addActionListener(this);
        jp.add(btn);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExceptionTest().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(jtf.getText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Number accepted");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "This text field accept only integers", "Invalid Input",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not extend JDialog instead of JFrame?

Comment: Is any performance degradation using JFrame instead of JDialog..?

Comment: No, but JDialog is used for dialogs which you are creating with JFrame.